# Correct way of using useReducer with useContext in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context, use-context

I am a new React developer, implementing global state in my app. Im using useReducer with Context API to cache form search data, but I feel I'm using the reducer wrong, even if it works. I am preparing payload BEFORE calling **dispatchSearchData**, instead of doing it directly inside reducer:

```
import React, { createContext, useReducer, useMemo, useEffect } from "react";

const initialData = {
  from: "",
  to: "",
  date_go: "",
  date_back: "",
  passengers: "",
};

const dataReducer = (searchData, newData) => {
  if (newData === null) {
    localStorage.removeItem("currentSearchData");
    return initialData;
  }
  return { ...searchData, ...newData };
};

const localData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentSearchData"));

export const SearchDataContext = createContext({});

export const SearchDataProvider = (props) => {
  const [searchData, dispatchSearchData] = useReducer(dataReducer, localData || initialData);
  const searchDataValue = useMemo(
    () => ({
      searchData,
      setSearchData,
    }),
    [searchData, setSearchData],
  );
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("currentSearchData", JSON.stringify(searchData));
  }, [searchData]);

  return <SearchDataContext.Provider value={searchDataValue}>{props.children}</SearchDataContext.Provider>;
};
```

An example of calling it:

```
let search = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatchSearchData(formData);
    setServiceData(null);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the community, Manuel! Will search data be updated only after completing a single form? If so, you might not need a reducer. Reducers are most helpful when there's complete state logic, or when state data depends on the previous state. In this case, looks like you might only be updating `searchData` when the form is submitted.

Comment: @fiz Ah thanks! I can stick to using useState in this case then. If my state was more complex, for example a complex object, and I only need to update one property at a time, would it make more sense to use `useReducer`?

Comment: Indeed. For example, checkout the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer and imagine that there were several more `action.type`s like taking the square root, multiple, subtract by another number, etc. In that case, you can just tell the reducer, "hey reducer, this is a type 'multiply' and here the data you'll need to perform the operation." Then the reducer takes that data and performs the operation and saves it to state for you." Hope this helps

Comment: Awesome! Thank you, i understand it much better now